# Block-indent Xcode

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping

Is there a way to remap <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in order to produce a block indent in Xcode (like Visual Studio)?

I added a key binding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to override <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and it is working.

Even if I change <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to <kbd>Tab</kbd> and resolve the mapping conflicts, it doesn't work.

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the Key Bindings tab of Xcode's preferences. Go to the Text Editing tab. Within that tab, there's an inner tab control. Select "Indentation". There's a pop-up menu labeled Tab Key with options Indents in leading whitespace, Indents always, and Inserts tab character. It sounds like you want Indents always.

Comment: I set `Tab Key` to `Indent always` and it doesn't work for me. I decided to use `⌥`+ `tab` as an easy workaround.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that preference setting just doesn't work sensibly. File a bug with Apple.

Comment: I will file a bug. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can indent a line of code or a selected block of code as follows:

Command-[ move code left
Command-] move code right

Comment: @imobilizer: He clearly knows about that since he mentions it in his question. He specifically wanted to use Tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remap the standard Xcode's Cmnd+[ to Tab, you can do the following:

1) Install a program called "Karabiner".

2) Go to Preferences ~> "Misc and Uninstall"

3) In "Custom Setting" section click on the "Open private.xml" button

4) Open the file and replace its content with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<root>
    <item>
        <name>Tab instead of Command+[</name>
        <identifier>private.swap_tab_and_cmnd+[</identifier>
        <autogen>
            __KeyToKey__
            KeyCode::TAB, ModifierFlag::NONE,
            KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::NONE
        </autogen>
    </item> 
</root>
```

5) Go to Preferences ~> "Change Key" ~> click on "Reload XML" button

6) Put a tick in the checkbox which is called "Tab instead of Command+["

7) Enjoy
[image]

PS: Please note that this setting works globally on your machine, not just in Xcode. However, I am sure that google might help you to find a solution how to customize it even further, applying the changes only to Xcode.

Answer (score -1):

You can indent a line of code or a selected block of code as follows:

Command-[ move code left
Command-] move code right